# Display RGB colors from two changing values

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I have two values (between 0 and 255), from audio sources.
I'm trying to display two different RGB colours, a rectangle split by the middle, the colors from these two changing numbers, the colors changing as the numbers.

thank for you help, I know it's simple, but i'm really stuck.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

To show a “split rectangle,” I would suggest using two `panel` objects side by side.

You can control the `panel` object’s colour using the `bgcolor` (or `bgfillcolor`) message followed by a list of four numbers, e.g.: `bgcolor 1 0 0 0.5`

The numbers correspond to Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha (opacity) and are all in the range of 0–1. So `bgcolor 1 0 0 0.5` would set the colour of the `panel` to 100% red and 50% transparent.

In your case, you have values 0–255 so you need to scale those down to 0–1 and then decide how exactly you want to map them. For example, if you wanted each `panel` to be white when the value is 255, black when it is 0, and some shade of grey in between, you could do something like this:

```
value → [scale 0 255 0. 1.] → (bgcolor $1 $1 $1 1) → [panel]
```

[image: Max patch showing a value 0–255 scaled to 0–1 controlling the colour of a panel object using a bgcolor message]

Some notes:

- The last two arguments of `scale` must be floats, otherwise it will just output integers 0 and 1.
- The `$1` syntax of the message box gets replaced by input. You could decide for example to only control the green part of the colour: `bgcolor 0 $1 0 1`.
- If your value changes very frequently, you might want to limit how often it updates the colour. Most screens won’t update faster than 60 times per second, so changing the colour every millisecond for example is a waste of resources. If you’re using `snapshot~` to get the value from audio, you could use an argument of `17` or higher, to limit the values to less than 60 times per second (1000ms / 60 = 16.6…). Alternatively, you could use the `speedlim` object to limit how often you recalculate your colour.